# Padding and reshaping pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, padding

I have a dataframe with the following form:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3],'Time':[0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1],
                     'sig':[2,3,1,4,2,0,2,3,5],'sig2':[9,2,8,0,4,5,1,1,0],
                     'group':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B','A','A']})

print(data)

   ID  Time  sig  sig2 group
0   1     0    2     9     A
1   1     1    3     2     A
2   1     2    1     8     A
3   2     0    4     0     B
4   2     1    2     4     B
5   2     2    0     5     B
6   2     3    2     1     B
7   3     0    3     1     A
8   3     1    5     0     A
```

I want to reshape and pad such that each 'ID' has the same number of Time values, the sig1,sig2 are padded with zeros (or mean value within ID) and the group carries the same letter value.  The output after repadding would be :

```
data_pad = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],'Time':[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3],
                     'sig1':[2,3,1,0,4,2,0,2,3,5,0,0],'sig2':[9,2,8,0,0,4,5,1,1,0,0,0],
                     'group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','A']})

print(data_pad)

    ID  Time  sig1  sig2 group
0    1     0     2     9     A
1    1     1     3     2     A
2    1     2     1     8     A
3    1     3     0     0     A
4    2     0     4     0     B
5    2     1     2     4     B
6    2     2     0     5     B
7    2     3     2     1     B
8    3     0     3     1     A
9    3     1     5     0     A
10   3     2     0     0     A
11   3     3     0     0     A
```

My end goal is to ultimately reshape this into something with shape (number of ID, number of time points, number of sequences {2 here}).

It seems that if I pivot `data`, it fills in with nan values, which is fine for the signal values, but not the groups.  I am also hoping to avoid looping through data.groupby('ID'), since my actual data has a large number of groups and the looping would likely be very slow.

Comment: Could you maybe add an expected output in more visual format. I'm having hard time trying to understand what exactly you want to do.

Comment: This is much better question than your other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach creating the new index with `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` and using it to `reindex` on the `Time` column:

```
df = data.set_index(['ID', 'Time'])
# define a the new index
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], 
                                 df.index.levels[1]], 
                                 names=['ID', 'Time'])
# reindex using the above multiindex
df = df.reindex(ix, fill_value=0)
# forward fill the missing values in group
df['group'] = df.group.mask(df.group.eq(0)).ffill()
```

---

```
print(df.reset_index())

    ID   Time  sig  sig2 group
0    1     0    2     9     A
1    1     1    3     2     A
2    1     2    1     8     A
3    1     3    0     0     A
4    2     0    4     0     B
5    2     1    2     4     B
6    2     2    0     5     B
7    2     3    2     1     B
8    3     0    3     1     A
9    3     1    5     0     A
10   3     2    0     0     A
11   3     3    0     0     A
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
(data.pivot_table(columns='Time', index=['ID','group'], fill_value=0)
     .stack('Time')
     .sort_index(level=['ID','Time'])
     .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
    ID group  Time  sig  sig2
0    1     A     0    2     9
1    1     A     1    3     2
2    1     A     2    1     8
3    1     A     3    0     0
4    2     B     0    4     0
5    2     B     1    2     4
6    2     B     2    0     5
7    2     B     3    2     1
8    3     A     0    3     1
9    3     A     1    5     0
10   3     A     2    0     0
11   3     A     3    0     0
```